# jquery - setting menu active states for a sprite based navigation where each class name is unique

Tags: jquery, css

I'm wondering how to do this with JQuery. I have a menu where each item's class name needs to be unique, because the css for the item selects a unique background position of a sprite which all the menu items share. So when the item is clicked, I need to trigger a unique active state class name as well. What's the best way to do this? Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="trailer">Trailer</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="bios">Bios</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="photos">Photos</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="synopsis">Synopsis</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="news">News</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#menu a { background: url(../images/menu.png) no-repeat; height:16px; overflow:hidden; display:block; text-indent:-10000px; float:left; margin-left:63px;}
#menu a:first-child { margin-left: 0;}
#menu a.trailer { width: 91px;}
#menu a.trailer:hover, #menu a.trailer_active { background-position: 0px -20px;}
#menu a.bios { width: 50px;  background-position: -153px 0;}
#menu a.bios:hover, #menu a.bios_active { background-position: -153px -20px;}
#menu a.photos { width:86px; background-position: -272px 0;}
#menu a.photos:hover, #menu a.photos_active { background-position: -272px -20px;}
#menu a.synopsis { width:103px; background-position: -423px 0;}
#menu a.synopsis:hover, #menu a.synopsis_active { background-position: -423px -20px;}
#menu a.news { width:62px; background-position: -579px 0;}
#menu a.news:hover, #menu a.news_active { background-position: -579px -20px;}
```

Comment: You don't want to use `:active`?

Comment: I don't get the question. Why not adding a classname to the clicked(active) anchor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this in your jquery

```
$('#menu>a').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active')
}
```

and change your 'active' rules in css like this:

```
#menu a.trailer:hover, #menu a.trailer.active { background-position: 0px -20px;}
```

so with a dot instead of an underscore

Answer (score 2):

Append `'_active'` to the class name when an anchor is clicked, if the anchor's class name does not already end with `'_active'`.

```
var re = /_active$/g;

$('#menu').delegate('a[class]', 'click', function ()
{
    var $this = $(this),
        className = this.className;

    if (className.match(re)) return;

    // remove _active from siblings
    $this.siblings().attr('class', function (i, val)
    {
        return val.replace(re, '');
    });

    // add _active to self
    this.className = className + '_active';
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/xppZu/

Note, this assumes that anchors will have **no** other classes applied.

Answer (score 1):

Ehhrr, either I get the question completely wrong or my fellow stackoverflowers overcomplicate things here.

```
$('#menu').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```